# Checkmarks don't show in checkbox on Window.print Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, css, checkbox

I am using AngularJs to display a few checkboxes.  I have a click event which writes the current html to a window using `document.write`.  However, when the new window opens for printing, none of the checkboxes are checked.

Here is the function which prints the document to the window:

```
$scope.printForm = function () {
    var doc = document.getElementById('myForm').outerHTML;
    var myWindow = $window.open('', '', 'width=1100, height=1000');

    myWindow.document.write(doc);
    myWindow.print();
};
```

Here is the HTML for the checkboxes:

```
`<div ng-repeat="c in f.Choices" >
<input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="true" ng-model="c.isSelected" />&nbsp;&nbsp;{{c.vchDescription}} </div>`
```

Here is what it looks like BEFORE I click "printForm"[image]

And here is what it looks like after I click "printForm":[image]

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Document in the new window is not an angular app.

Comment: That makes sense.  Any idea as how to solve the issue?

Comment: Why do you need a new window? Isn't it enough to have `@media print` in your style sheet?

Comment: Or you can create a directive to generate HTML from your model.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use that.  Every example I've seen of printing Html using Angular does it the way I am doing it here.  If you have a better way, by all means share.  It would probably help a lot of people.  Thanks!

Comment: Even the Angular print directive I found does not show the checkmarks.  See here http://embed.plnkr.co/pzIfYGIOt7L8eFSJxWlu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this one out by accident.  Changing `ng-model="c.isSelected"` tp `ng-checked="c.isSelected"` allowed the checkmarks to show in the checkboxes.

Simple code change below solved it:

```
                            <div ng-repeat="c in f.Choices" >
                           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="true" ng-checked="c.isSelected" checked/>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{c.vchDescription}}
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Mehod #1: generate HTML**

Model is passed to `print-button` directive. It generates HTML and writes it to the opened window.

SO does not allow to open new windows. See working example on [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/x6zXJoWDLayhoIKnAQB2?p=preview).

**Method #2: use CSS media queries**

There's no need to open a new window. Just style document for print media accordingly.

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('AppController', function($window) {
  this.options = [
    {label: 'Foo', checked: false},
    {label: 'Bar', checked: true}
  ];
  
  // if you just need to print
  this.print = function() {
    $window.print();
  };
})

// directive to generate HTML from model
.directive('printButton', function($window) {
  return {
    template: '<button ng-click="generate()">Open in new window</button>',
    scope: {
      data: '='
    },
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.generate = function() {
        var win = $window.open("", "bar", "width=200,height=100");
        var html = '';
        scope.data.forEach((val) => {
          html += '<input type="checkbox"' + ((val.checked) ? ' checked=checked' : '') + '"/><label>'+val.label+'</label>';
        })
        win.document.write(html);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
@media print {
  .not-printable {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController as app">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="not-printable">This will not be printed</h1>
  <div ng-repeat="opt in app.options">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="opt.checked" /><label ng-bind="opt.label"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="not-printable">
    <div print-button data="app.options"></div>
    <button ng-click="app.print()">Simply print</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It works great if the only thing on the page is the checkboxes.  However, there is actually usually several printable pages of information included with the checkboxes in my application.  Using your directive here http://plnkr.co/edit/NgODZp3N3D1vZXgU8Hci?p=preview, the only thing that prints is the checkboxes.

Comment: See edited answer if you just want a different page look for printing. I added `print` method to controller and some CSS to hide elements you don't want to appear in printed document. You don't need a directive in that case.

Comment: Thanks, but $window.print() only prints what is visible and cuts off everything else.  I do appreciate your trying to help.

Comment: Then modify `printButton` directive with all the HTML needed and pass a whole model to it. Otherwise you are doing it not in an angular way.

Comment: You can also create printable view in the same page. `<div ng-if="printable"><!-- content --></div><button ng-click="printable = !printable">Print preview</button>`

Comment: BTW. I don't understand what do you mean by "cuts off everything else". If it's visible on page it will be printed. Split to pages of course.

Comment: It doesn't print everything.  The doc opens in a modal with a scrollbar.  Depending on which doc they selected, it can go on for many pages.  Getting the element by id and printing prints it all.  Just doing window.print does not.

Comment: Update your question and tell us (other users and me) more about your application. There might be problems somewhere else. Paste some code to show how your report is generated.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It looks as if the problem was just with using ng-model to check the boxes rather than ng-checked.